# how to get child tags using each statement?

Tags: jquery, svg

How to get the child tags using each statement.

```
<svg id="svgcontent" >
  <g id="layer" > <g>
  <g id="test1" > <g>
  <g id="test2"></g>
  <g id="test2"> </g>
<svg>
```

i need  below output How to get this using jquery.

```
<g id="test1" > <g>
<g id="test2"></g>
<g id="test2"> </g>
```

i tried this

```
var element = "";
$('#svgcontent g').each(function () {                                   
    var cur_class = $(this).attr("class");                                  
    if(cur_class != "layer") {
        element =   element+$(this).html();
    }
}
```

Comment: where's your jQuery code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<svg id="svgcontent" >
    <g id="layer" class='layer' > </g>
    <g id="test1" > </g>
    <g id="test2"></g>
    <g id="test2"> </g>
<span>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#svgcontent g').each(function () {                                  
    if($(this).hasClass('layer')) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save whole html tag to a variable,You need to use outerHTML property to get whole html of a tag since html() only return inner html of a html tag and in your html you are using id for  tag and in your js code you are using .attr('class');

So you need to like this

HTML

```
  <svg id="svgcontent" >
  <g id="layer" > </g>
  <g id="test1" > </g>
  <g id="test2"></g>
  <g id="test2"> </g>
<svg>
```

JS :

```
$(function(){
   var element="";
$('#svgcontent g').each(function(){                                   
  var cur_class=$(this).attr("id");                                  
  if(cur_class!="layer"){
      element=   element+$(this)[0].outerHTML;
  }    
});
});
```

Or you can also do this using not selecter like this

```
$(function(){
        var element="";
        $('#svgcontent g[id!=layer]').each(function(){                                   

              element =element+ $(this)[0].outerHTML;   
        });
         console.log(element);
        });
```